# how to change value of a member of a struct using a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I cannot solve the following issue:

I have a struct like:

```
enum node_type {
  FRUIT,
  QUESTION
};
typedef enum node_type type;

struct node {
  type node_type;
  union node_info {
    char *fruit;
    char *question;
  }data;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
};
typedef struct node node_p;
```

When i try to access the member type (which is an enum), i can't change its value. It compiles, but when i run it i get a 'Segmentation Fault'.
In my main method i have sth like this:

```
node_p *node1 = NULL;
node1->node_type = FRUIT;
node1->data.question = "Apple";
```

Does anyone know what the problem seems to be?

Comment: You are probably attempting to write into a memory address which does not have *Write* access permission. This memory address happens to be 0 (the offset of the `node_type` field from the beginning of the `node` structure that is supposed to be allocated at address 0). Did you have any specific reason to set the `node1` variable to point to that memory address (`NULL`)?

Comment: `NULL` is a sentinel value which indicates an invalid pointer. So you explicitly create an invalid pointer... and then proceed to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for the node. For example

```
node_p *node1 = malloc( sizeof( node_p ) );
if ( node1 != NULL )
{
    node1->node_type = FRUIT;
    node1->data.question = "Apple";
}
```

And do not forget to free the allocated mempry then the node will not be needed any more using function free:

```
free( node1 );
```

Comment: Your answer implies that OP must allocate this memory dynamically. This is not mandatory. As long as the `node1` variable is set to point to a large enough memory space dedicated to a `node` object, OP's code is good. For example, a pre-allocated `node` object on the stack, or a large enough array (in which case, address alignment is also critical for success).

Comment: @barak manos If code would be good he never gets the segmentation fault. So your remark has no sense because OP uses a null pointer.

Comment: What kind of answer is that? Did you skip the "As long as" prefix at the beginning of the sentence??? BTW, I was merely trying to suggest that you should not make OP think that `malloc` was the only way. Oh and hmmm... I'm not the one who just took off your up-vote here, so please don't go around down-voting random posts of mine...

Comment: @barak manos I think If he has a question he can ask it himself.

Comment: OP asks why his code isn't working, when clearly the pointer is set to `NULL` and then used in order to access the pointed memory. It's not like he forgot to initialize it. He clearly doesn't understand the idea in using pointers. I think that a deeper explanation would be a little more informative in this case.

Comment: If you're allocating memory for `node1` you should also allocate memory for its' internal pointers, e.g. data.question, otherwise it won't work (besides by luck).

Comment: @Felipe T. Bortolon There is no need to allocate memory for question because he uses string literals.

Comment: Sure thing @VladfromMoscow! As long as he uses string literals he won't have any problems.